# There are 2 women, 4 children and 5 men in a queue. How many ways can you order them so that the children are always separated

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

This is an exercise from my as level book in probability and statistics, I was wondering how many ways the children could be ordered if none of them were next to each other. The answer is 8467200, I have no idea how to get there though.

**My attempt:**

So far I’ve tried doing it this way: I find all the ways the children are together and subtract it from the possible ways, this has given me a wrong answer tho. I’ve realized there are two things that will remain constant. $7!$ ( the number of people who aren’t children) which is being times’d by $4!$ ( number of children) and then another number times-ing all this. I got the number correct for when the $4$ children are all together. The next scenario is when $3$ are together and one is apart, then $2$ groups of $2$ and I think. I think that’s it since I already did the $3$ and $1$ apart.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hint:  arrange the children in some order.  Now consider the gaps between them (including the one before the first child and the one after the last child).  What do we know about the number of people in each gap?  Does this resemble a standard problem?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Sorry about all the confusion I’ve caused and how the question was received. So far I’ve tried doing it this way: I find all the ways the children are together and subtract it from the possible ways, this has given me a wrong answer tho. I’ve realized there are two things that will remain constant. 7! ( the number of people who aren’t children) which is being times’d by 4! ( number of children) and then another number times-ing all this. I got the number correct for when the 4 children are all together. The next scenario is when 3 are together and one is apart, then 2 groups of 2 and I think

Comment: Continuing, I think that’s it since I already did the 3 and 1 apart.

Comment: You misunderstood the question.  No two of the children may be adjacent.

Answer (score 1):

First arrange the men and women in a queue : number of ways of doing this is $7!$

Then in the 8 gaps formed between them choose 4 and arrange the children into them:
$\binom{8}{4}4!$
Multiplying the two ,we get our answer $$7!* 4!* \binom{8}{4}$$